# How to set instance variables in camunda using the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, camunda

I am trying to use the [PHP SDK in camunda](http://camunda.github.io/camunda-bpm-php-sdk/) but it is not clearly documented how to set process variables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the `ProcessInstanceService`.

Below is a snippet for the demo Invoice Receipt.

```
$camundaAPI = new \org\camunda\php\sdk\Api('http://localhost:8080/engine-rest');
$processDefinitionRequest = new \org\camunda\php\sdk\entity\request\ProcessDefinitionRequest();
$processDefinitions = $camundaAPI->processDefinition->getDefinitions($processDefinitionRequest);

foreach($processDefinitions AS $pd) {
    echo 'Process deployment id: ' . $pd->getDeploymentId() . "\n";
}

// Process instance (make the assumption that $pd is the desired object).
$procInstance = $camundaAPI->processDefinition->startInstanceByKey($pd->getKey(), $processDefinitionRequest);

// ProcessInstanceService
$procInstanceService = new \org\camunda\php\sdk\service\ProcessInstanceService('http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/');
$var = new \org\camunda\php\sdk\entity\request\VariableRequest();
$var->setType('String');
$var->setValue('H4CK4THON2014');
$procInstanceService->putProcessVariable($procInstance->getId(), 'creditor', $var);
```